# Foreach numa CheckList em c#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void Checked()
{
    foreach (ListViewItem listItem in listView.Items)
    {
        if (cb_selectAll.Checked == true)
        {
            listItem.Checked = true;
        }
        if (cb_selectAll.Checked == false)
        {
            listItem.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Tenho este código aqui. Só que no foreach está a dar o seguinte erro:

> Cannot convert type 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinListView.UltraListViewItem' to System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.

Como eu posso eliminar esse erro?

A list View está assim :

```
private void Search()
{
    mUpdater = new DatabaseUpdaterService();

    mUpdater.Initialize(false, null);

    DataTable dt = mUpdater.GetVersionCheckBoxToUpdate();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        this.listView.Items.Add(row["ID"].ToString(), row["Version"].ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O erro é bem claro, `listView.Items` é uma coleção de `UltraListViewItem`.

A `ListView` que está sendo usada não é a padrão do WinForms e sim uma implementação própria.

Sem maiores detalhes, a solução que posso propor é alterar o `foreach` para ficar assim

```
foreach (UltraListViewItem listItem in listView.Items)
```

De qualquer forma, ainda é possível usar `var` e deixar que o tipo seja definido automaticamente, assim

```
foreach (var listItem in listView.Items)
```

Comment: muito obrigada. ainda sou nova nisto.

Answer (score 1):

Para quem quiser a solução está aqui:

```
UltraListViewSubItem subItem;
List<UltraListViewSubItem> subItemArray;
UltraListViewItem item = new UltraListViewItem(
                row["Version"].ToString(), subItemArray.ToArray());
                item.Key = row["ID"].ToString();
```